# C# Reflection : Finding Attributes on a Member Field

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, field

I may be asking this incorrectly, but can/how can you find fields on a class within itself... for example...

```
public class HtmlPart {
  public void Render() {
    //this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OptionalAttribute), false);
  }
}

public class HtmlForm {
  private HtmlPart _FirstPart = new HtmlPart();      
  [Optional] //<-- how do I find that?
  private HtmlPart _SecondPart = new HtmlPart();
}
```

Or maybe I'm just doing this incorrectly... How can I call a method and then check for attributes applied to itself?

**Also, for the sake of the question** - I'm just curious if it was possible to find attribute information *without knowing/accessing the parent class!*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think what you are trying to do is not possible...

In the `Render` method, you want to get a possible attribute applied to the object. The attribute belongs to the field `_SecondPart` witch belongs to the class `HtmlForm`.

For that to work you would have to pass the calling object to the `Render` method:

```
    public class HtmlPart {
        public void Render(object obj) {
            FieldInfo[] infos = obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var fi in infos)
            {
                if (fi.GetValue(obj) == this && fi.IsDefined(typeof(OptionalAttribute), true))
                    Console.WriteLine("Optional is Defined");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - It seemed 'possible', but then again I figured there was just enough missing that it couldn't work.

Comment: No, the Render method can perfectly well access typeof(HtmlForm) instead of obj.GetType(), then you don't need the obj anymore. Of course, if HtmlForm itself was private, then you might need to find it through Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => !t.IsGeneric && !t.IsNested && t.FullName == "MyNamespace.HtmlForm") or something like that.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an example of given a single object how to find if any public or private fields on that object have a specific property:

```
var type = typeof(MyObject);
foreach (var field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
             BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    if (field.IsDefined(typeof(ObsoleteAttribute), true))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
    }

}
```

For the second part of your question you can check if an attribute is defiend on the current method using:

```
MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().IsDefined(typeof(ObsoleteAttribute));
```

**Edit**

To answer your edit yes it is possible without knowing the actual type. The following function takes a type Parameter and returns all fields which have a given attribute. Someone somewhere is going to either know the Type you want to search, or will have an instance of the type you want to search.

Without that you'd have to do as Jon Skeet said which is to enumerate over all objects in an assembly.

```
   public List<FieldInfo> FindFields(Type type, Type attribute)
    {
        var fields = new List<FieldInfo>();
        foreach (var field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                           BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                           BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            if (field.IsDefined(attribute, true))
            {
                fields.Add(field);
            }

        }
        return fields;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find fields within a class using `Type.GetFields`, and you can find attributes applied to a field using `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes` or `IsDefined` - but if you need to find all the fields of a particular type, you're going to have to:

- Iterate over all the assemblies you want to search
- Iterate over all the types within each assembly
- Iterate over all the fields within each type
- Check for the attribute's presence/absence for each field

Now, if you're really trying to find out "is a particular attribute applied to a field whose value is a reference to 'this' object" then that's even harder - because you'd have to know all about every object in the system. You should also bear in mind that there could be *two* fields both with the same value, i.e. referencing the same object. Would the object count as "optional" in that case or not?

Basically, if the object should have a property (e.g. optional or not) then that must be a property of the object itself, not the field containing the property.

It could be that I'm misinterpreting what you're trying to do, but I *suspect* it's either not feasible or at least not a good idea. Could you explain the bigger picture here? What are you really trying to achieve with this attribute?

Comment: Thanks for the response - Right now it's more of an experiment than anything else. I wondered if it was even possible since it was a quirky way to try and reach that information.