# c#: get class member by name (reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection

I have two lists (list) l1 & l2.
i'm getting from outside the name of the list i want to use (let say l1).

how can i find requested list ?

do i need to use getMember method ?

thanks

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are asking. A code snippet will help.

Comment: It sounds like you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.  Can you tell us more generally what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use reflection, but it's fairly expensive.  Here's a question that outlines how to do that:

[C# Reflection : Finding Attributes on a Member Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803221/c-reflection-finding-attributes-on-a-member-field)

Given that the list name is known at compile time, you could consider implementing a method that accepts the string name of the list and returns a reference to the appropriate list using a `switch` statement or `if` statement.

```
static IList FindList(string name)
{
  if (name == "l1") { return l1; }
  else if (name == "l2") { return l2; }
  else throw Exception("List " + name + " not found.");
}
```

That will be faster at runtime than using reflection but requires maintenance (if you have enough lists to warrant the effort, you could code generate that method).

Comment: You could also set this up as a Dictionary, keyed to possible values for `name`. Just saying; if you ever needed an l3, it would be a matter of simply adding it to the Dictionary, instead of also having to extend the switch statement.

Comment: or he can use Dictionary<string, List<someobject>>, put both lists (or more) into this dictionary with name as key and then it's easy to get them out.

Comment: @KeithS you beat me for couple of seconds :-)