# Validate Input of UserControl in Window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Currently I have a `UserControl` contained within a window. The `UserControl` is made up of two text boxes. The `UserControl` is an element in my `MainWindow`. Outside the scope of my `UserControl` is my submit button in my window. I would like to enable and disable the button whenever the boxes text contents are not null or null.

`UserControl` XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myClass.myUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel Background="White">
        <DockPanel>
            <Label x:Name="lbl1" Content="First Box:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtbox1"/>
            <Label x:Name="lbl1" Content="Second Box:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtbox2"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

View Model:

```
using System;

namespace myClass {

    partial class UserControlViewModel: ViewModelBase {

        private bool _validInput;

        public UserControlViewModel() {
            validInput = false;
        }

        public object validInput {
            get { return _validInput; }
            set {
            _validInput = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("validInput");
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModelBase:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace myClass {
    class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is deciding on how to handle this validation, my button's `isEnabled` property is currently bounded to the `validInput` boolean of the view model. However, the contents of the user control are not accessible in my window as I have abstracted it as a separate userControl item (I plan on having different user controls available to be shown in the window).

`MainWindow` XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="myClass.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:myClass"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="356" Width="699" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <uc:UserControlViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <UserControl x:Name="usrControl"/>

        <Button x:Name="btn" Content="Create" Click="btn_Click" IsEnabled = "{Binding validInput}"/>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

`MainWindow` C#:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace myClass {

    public partial class MainWindow: Window {

        UserControlViewModel view;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            view = new UserControlViewModel();
            DataContext = view;
        } 
}
```

I need to be able to check the contents of the text boxes in the `UserControl` from the `MainWindow` as my view is in the `MainWindow`, however the contents are inaccessible to me and it doesn't make sense to have the view in the `UserControl`. How should I go about solving this?

Comment: Add a boolean dependency property to the UserControl that is updated whenever the Text property of the two TextBoxes changes, e.g. in a TextChanged event handler that is attached to both of them.

Comment: How will the dependency property effect the view model of the window if the property is in the `UserControl`?

Comment: You would just bind it to your view model, with Mode=OneWayToSource.

Comment: You should consider implementing IDataErrorInfo on your class. Look at this post for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136814/how-to-catch-dataannotations-validation-in-mvvm

Comment: @Clemens could you please provide a small working example? I don't see how this works in my case.

Answer (score -1):

I've created a similar project. Mainly to do this, validate through your c# code. Basically

(i don't remember id its .content or .text to get the value)

```
if(txtbox1.Content == ---or--- (textbox1.Content).Equals(Whatever)){

   ----code---

}

else{
    MessageBox.Show("Error")
}
```

instead of 'disabling' the button (which I don't think you can do) just make it so if invalid, the user knows or just doesn't do anything.

unrelated: if you are wanting a certain input instead of a blank textbox input, you could use this code to give a base if user leaves empty

```
private void txtbox1_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtbox1.Text.Equals("your origional text"))
            {
                Name_Text.Text = "";
            }
        }

private void txtbox1_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Name_Text.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                Name_Text.Text = "your origional text";
            }
        }
```

hope this helps