# C# Reflection : Finding Custom Attributes on a Class Property

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

I would like to define a custom attribute for specific properties of a class. Based on reflection it should be possible to check if the property is annotated with this attribute or not. The first Assert.AreEqual(2, infos.Length) passes but the second Assert.AreEqual(1, properties.Count) fails with properties.Count = 0. What am I missing?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test.UnitTesting.Rest.ParameteterModels
{
    public class IncludableAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        [Includable]
        public List<string> List1 { get; set; }

        public List<string> List2 { get; set; }

        public TestClass()
        {

        }
    }


    [TestClass]
    public class IncludeParamaterModelTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            List<string> properties = new List<string>();

            FieldInfo[] infos = typeof(TestClass).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, infos.Length);

            foreach (FieldInfo fi in infos)
            {
                if (fi.IsDefined(typeof(IncludableAttribute), true)) properties.Add(fi.Name);
            }
            Assert.AreEqual(1, properties.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

This question is similar to [C# Reflection : Finding Attributes on a Member Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803221/c-sharp-reflection-finding-attributes-on-a-member-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attribute is being applied to the *properties*. While you do have fields, they're created by the compiler - and your custom attribute isn't being applied to them. Your code is broadly equivalent to:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private List<string> list1;

[Includable]
public List<string> List1 { get { return list1; } set { list1 = value; } }

[CompilerGenerated]
private List<string> list2;
public List<string> List2 { get { return list2; } set { list2 = value; } }
```

As you can see, there are still two fields (`list1` and `list2`) - which is why your first assertion succeeds. However, neither of those have the `Includable` attribute. It's the `List1` *property* which does.

So you need to be asking for the properties rather than the fields. I'd also do this with LINQ rather than looping explicitly:

```
var properties = typeof(TestClass)
                     .GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                    BindingFlags.Public | 
                                    BindingFlags.Instance)
                     .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(IncludableAttribute), true)
                     .ToList();
```

(You may want to consider whether you really want to pick up non-public properties.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `GetProperties` instead of `GetFields` because you do not have any fields in `TestClass`, you have two *auto-implemented* properties.And `BindingFlags.NonPublic` flag seems unnecessary because your properties are defined as `public`.

```
var infos = typeof(TestClass)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | 
                           BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: The OP *does* have fields in `TestClass` - otherwise the assertion would fail. They're compiler-generated, but they're certainly there. They don't have the attributes though.

Comment: @JonSkeet you right, but there is no way to get them via Reflection right?

Comment: No, that's not true. The OP is already getting them - hence why the first assertion is working. (There's an assertion that there are two fields.) It's just a matter of what the attributes are applied to.